# Error building a newly created project in XCode 14

Tags: xcode, codesign

I created a new Objective C XIB application in XCode 14 on Mac OS Ventura. When I try to build the new project I get the following error message "Command CodeSign failed with nonzero exit code". Tried cleaning up build folder and rebuilding again, changing Signing Identify options in Build Settings, restarting XCode and Mac OS, deleting DerivedData folder but still getting the same error. Is there a way to fix the issue? Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Tried cleaning up build folder and rebuilding again, changing Signing Identify options in Build Settings, restarting XCode and Mac OS, deleting DerivedData folder but still getting the same error. Expect to be able to build and run the project.